# no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path xx

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have tried a lot of different answers on stack but none of them work. I am trying to add a repository as a submodule which contains another submodule. So what I do is this:

```
git submodule add -b develop git@github.com:submoduleRepo
```

The submodule is added to the repository and contains the folder of the submodule within it. However the folder is empty. So I follow up with this command:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Which returns me nothing. If I go to the directory of the submodule `cd submoduleRepo` and then type git submodule, I get:

```
fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'src/app/nestedSubmoduleRepo'
```

This is my .gitmodules of the main repo:

```
[submodule "submoduleRepo"]
    path = submoduleRepo
    url = git@github.com:submoduleRepo.git
    branch = develop
```

And within submoduleRepo/.gitmodules:

```
[submodule ".\\src\\app\\nestedSubmoduleRepo"]
    path = .\\src\\app\\nestedSubmoduleRepo
    url = git@github.com:nestedSubmoduleRepo.git
```

Why do I keep getting this error and is the directory not getting populated?

EDIT:

Once I've ran `--init --recursive` once it gives me the error:

```
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'submoduleRepo/src/app/nestedSubmoduleRepo' in .gitmodules
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'submoduleRepo'
```

My git config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:mainRepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "submoduleRepo"]
    url = git@github.com:submoduleRepo.git
    active = true
```

Comment: That's not a url. Try giving the protocol, e.g. `https://github.com/user/repo.git`

Comment: That doesn't work either. Also, the submoduleRepo which contains the nestedSubmoduleRepo also has the url written that way and it does work. I am able to access that url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your submodule repo is using backslashes in the `.gitmodules` file.  Git uses forward slashes for paths within the repository because they work across platforms (and backslashes do not), and it has no way of knowing whether your repository is intended to be cross platform or not.

You'll need to update the submodule repository to contain the proper entries in the file (and you should also drop the `.` path component as well).  Once you've committed that and updated the parent repository with the new commit, `git submodule update --init --recursive` should work properly.

Comment: `src/app/nestedSubmoduleRepo` then `git submodule update --init --recursive` did the trick! Thanks. Somewhat obvious but just in case someone struggles with it don't do `git submodule update --recursive --init`